# Какие есть бесплатные для коммерческого использования профилировщики кода на языке C#?

Tags: c#, поиск-библиотек, поиск-программ, профилирование

Какие бесплатные для коммерческого использования профилировщики кода можно использовать с языком C#? Знаю только библиотеку Benchmark.NET

Comment: Есть профайлеры проца и памяти в Visual Studio встроенные.

Comment: Не у всех пользователей есть Visual Studio, но там, насколько мне известно, только график показывает.

Comment: Вам многое неизвестно в таком случае.

Comment: Увы, использовать платные программы я не готов.

Answer (score 1):

Профилирование и анализ производительности обширная тема. Нужный вам ответ зависит от того что вам нужно исследовать в приложении: CPU, память, давление на GC, блокировки потоков, взаимодействие с сетью и т.д.

В общем случае вам может помочь поставляемый вместе с dotnet sdk инструмент `dotnet-trace` - стандартный профилировщик для .net core приложений.
Вы можете инструментировать работу приложения и выгрузить снепшот в Speedscope и анализировать что происходит с CPU.

Также, для windows есть мощный `PerfView`, этот инструмент умеет больше чем `dotnet-trace` и может захватывать память.

Для `asp.net core` есть прекрасный инструмент работающий внутри самого приложения - https://miniprofiler.com/
Умеет засекать время выполнения запросов http, их внутренних запросов в БД и покзать материализованый запрос SQL.